XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy in NextJs App with Axios and UploadThing
I am facing an issue with a XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy. I've started to create an app in NextJS in localhost so far. I just started to use Uploadthing to store my files and when I try to upload a file, I found out the file is well updated but not visible on my app.
Indeed I get the error below :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sea1.ingest.uploadthing.com/xxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
After some research online, I tried to add CORS headers in NextJS, by adding these lines to the next.config.mjs file :
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {domains: ["utfs.io"]},
    async headers() {
        return [
          {
            // matching all API routes
            source: "/api/:path*",
            headers: [
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
};    
export default nextConfig;

But it doesn't work and the error remain. How could I do to handle cross origin requests between my localhost and uploadthing?
You'll find below the code from where I get the error :
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import axios from "axios";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { Estates } from "@prisma/client";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Ban, ImageIcon, Pencil, PlusCircle} from "lucide-react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FileUpload } from "@/components/tools/files-upload";


interface ImageFormProps {
    initialData: Estates;
    estateId: string;
};

const formSchema = z.object({imageUrl: z.string().min(1, {message: "Image required"})});

export const ImageForm = ({initialData, estateId}: ImageFormProps) => {
    
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const toggleEdit = () => setIsEditing((current) => !current);
    const router = useRouter();
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({resolver: zodResolver(formSchema), defaultValues: {imageUrl: initialData?.description || ""}});
    const onSubmit = async(values:z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
        try {
            await axios.patch(`/api/estates/${estateId}`, values);
            toast.success("Picture updated")
            toggleEdit();
            router.refresh();
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error("An error occured");
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="mt-6 border bg-slate-100 rounded-md p-4">
            <div className="font-medium flex items-center justify-between"> 
                Photos initiales
                <Button onClick={toggleEdit} variant="ghost">
                    {isEditing && (<><Ban className="h-4 w-4"/></>)}
                    {!isEditing && !initialData.imageUrl && (<><PlusCircle className="h-4 w-4" /></>)}
                    {!isEditing && initialData.imageUrl && (<><Pencil className="h-4 w-4"/></>)}
                </Button>
            </div>
            {!isEditing && (!initialData.imageUrl ? (
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-60 bg-slate-200 rounded-md">
                    <ImageIcon className="h-10 w-10 text-slate-500" />
                </div>) : (
                    <div className="relative aspect-video mt-2">
                        <Image alt="Upload" fill className="object-cover rounded-md" src={initialData.imageUrl} />
                        current image
                    </div>
                )
            )}
            {isEditing && (
                <div>
                    <FileUpload endpoint="estateImage" onChange={(url) => {
                        if (url) {
                            onSubmit({imageUrl: url})
                        }
                    }}/>
                    <div className="text-xs text-muted-foreground mt-4">
                        Ratio 16:9 required for pictures
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>  
    )
} 

